# AWS | Не пускает на сайт с других стран

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Залил своё NodeJS/React приложение на AWS ElasticBeanstalk, получил SSL сертификат, настроил рулы в load balancer'е для редиректа с `http` на `https`. В Route 53 из записей у меня следующие:
выданные по дефолту NS (уже подконнекчены к Google Domains) и SOA.
прописал вручную запись типа А, record name - `domain.com`, Value/Route traffic to - алиас на мой Elastic Beanstalk.

Также настроен редирект с `www.domain.com` на `domain.com`. Я сделал это следующим образом: Создал s3 бакет с именем `www.domain.com`, регион - тот на котором находится Elastic Beanstalk, снимаю галочку с "Block all public access", и создаю его. Затем активирую static website hosting, Hosting type - Redirect requests for an object, host name - `domain.com`, protocol - `https`. Также сделал этот бакет с пермишеном паблик, добавив в bucket policy следующее:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "s3:GetObject",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::MY_BUCKET_NAME/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Далее создал CloudFront distribution (т.к. s3 не работает с `https` протоколом, как написано в оф. документации), в origin domain name указываю Bucket website endpoint из s3 bucket'a, меняю Viewer protocol policy на Redirect HTTP to HTTPS, выбираю custom ssl сертификат, добавляю Alternate domain name - `www.domain.com` и создаю его.

Задем иду в Route 53, создаю запись: Record name - `www.domain.com` Type - A Value/Route traffic to - алиас на CloudFront Domain name. Сохраняю и жду (ждал долго, часов 12). И что я вижу: на моем пк работает работает буквально всё, и редирект с `http` на `https`, и редирект с `www` на `root`. Но когда я подрубаю VPN Германии, например, то на сайт не пускает не по root домену, не по www, ошибка - ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED. (пробовал и США, и Румынию - тот же результат)

Что я делаю не так? Буду рад, если сможете помочь, ибо у меня уже закончились варианты

Comment: A что `nslookup` отвечает в первом и втором случае? Домен больше нигде в DNS не прописан?

Comment: С ВПНом при `nslookup domain.com` в результате запроса выдает только `domain.com`. А без ВПНа выдает как `domain.com`, так и `Adresses: *и тут 3 ipшника*`